# Presentation of projective variety example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, affine-varieties

I am studying the following example in my algebraic geometry syllabus.

[image]

They refer to Theorem 5.1.5, which I put below. However, I don't see how this theorem is applied in this example. Could someone clarify this please?

[image]

Comment: $X_{01}$ is the subvariety of $X_0 \cong \mathbb A^2$ on which $x_1 \ne 0$, so it is the affine variety $D(x_1)$ . You should probably write this as $D$ of the restriction of $x_1$ to $X_0$, but the coordinate conventions in this example are making my head spin so I don't want to get it wrong.

Comment: OK, I found the notes you're working from and read the coordinate convention (which is backwards from most common conventions FYI). To properly describe $X_{01}$ as a subvariety of $X_0$, we want to refer to it as $D(x_{01})$

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your comment ! However, could you elaborate on how to then see $X_0=D(x_0)$ as a closed subset of $\mathbf{A}^2$ ?

Comment: $D(x_0)$ is an *open* subset of $\mathbb A^2$ obtained by deleting the line $V(x_0)$. Theorem 5.15 explains how such subsets can be exhibited as closed subsets of $\mathbb A^3$ (notice the increase in dimension) using the trick of Rabinowitz.